# More than 1 row in <Input type="textarea" />

Tags: input, textarea, rows, lines

I'm having troubles getting my `<input type="textarea" />` to have more than 1 row,

I tried adding the properties in the html, like you would do with a normal `<textarea></textarea>` like this: `<input type="textarea" rows="x" cols="x" />`

I even tried to do it in CSS, but it did not work.
I've searched all over the internet for a solution, but i can't seem to find a topic regarding my exact problem anywhere.

The textareas i'm experiencing this with, are on this website:
[Vilduhelst](http://trendlining.com/~vilduhel/)

When you press the "Lav dit eget dilemma" button they will appear.

I'm looking for either a HTML or CSS solution.

Comment: You need to use a <textarea> element. As a reference this are all the valid types for the input element with the new types on HTML 5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html

Comment: <input> tag is for Single Line TextBox, you can't make it mufti-line. For that use <textarea> instead of <input/>

Comment: Oh gosh, is that really the problem? I asked my hostmaster who is a professional deveoper for advice on this matter, and he couldn't figure out what was wrong -.-

Comment: [That's not valid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4).  It partially worked because it defaulted to `input type='text'`.

Answer (score 86):

Why not use the `<textarea>` tag?

```html
<textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
```

Comment: I tried using the <textarea> tag, but it gave a way different front end output, and i figured i'd prefer to learn why it doesn't work, and what can be done to make it work. Instead of just using another solution and editting the css a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure that "textarea" is a valid value for attribute "type" of `<input>` 
The textarea tag is what I've always used. What's the problem with it anyway? It renders fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/tLWrP/

Comment: You are right, i just changed it to <textarea> and it rendered as it should. When i tried yesterday, the output was completely different though.

Comment: Might have been a typo in the tag name, or maybe incorrect attribute-values. Good it worked!

Comment: [`input type='textarea'` is not valid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4).  It partially worked because it simply defaulted to `input type='text'`, hence why the OP originally only saw one line.

Answer (score 36):

Although `<input>` ignores the `rows` attribute, you can take advantage of the fact that `<textarea>` doesn't have to be inside `<form>` tags, but can still be a part of a form by referencing the form's id:

```
<form method="get" id="testformid">
    <input type="submit" />
</form> 
<textarea form ="testformid" name="taname" id="taid" cols="35" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

Of course, `<textarea>` now appears below "submit" button, but maybe you'll find a way to reposition it.

Comment: Thanks for giving an example of how to use it!

Answer (score 23):

As said by *Sparky* in comments on many answers to this question, **there is NOT** any `textarea` value for the `type` attribute of the `input` tag.

On other terms, the following markup is **not valid** :

```html
<input type="textarea" />
```

And the browser replaces it by the **default** :

```html
<input type="text" />
```

**To define a multi-lines text input, use :**

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

See [the *textarea* element documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

The "input" tag doesn't support rows and cols attributes. This is why the best alternative is to use a textarea with rows and cols attributes. You can still add a "name" attribute and also there is a useful "wrap" attribute which can serve pretty well in various situations.