# INPUT as multiline TEXTAREA with -webkit-appearance

Tags: css

Is it possible to make `INPUT` look like `TEXTAREA`, at least in Chrome? `DIV` converted to TEXTAREA with `-webkit-appearance: textarea` works fine but `INPUT` does not.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037548/how-can-make-an-inputtype-text-element-to-work-as-textarea

Comment: It is impossible now. Multi-line text is intended only for `textarea`

Comment: ...and for `DIV` appearing as `TEXTAREA`. That is why I found it strange that I can simulate it by `DIV` but not by `INPUT` which is a closer element.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Semantically and with accessibility in mind it isn't recommended to confused the two or fake the appearance. Just for clarity this is a single-line text input:

```
<input type="text" name="">
```

And this is a multiline text input:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">Default value.</textarea>
```

Fundamentally they were built to be like that unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!
Yes, I know it is not recommended but in this case it's the only solution as we have a Saas software and no entry to admin panel edition. We can only make a kind of patch on a browser, user-side CSS rule.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah it's one of those things that it just isn't designed to do. I've just tested word-wrap and word-break as well as the overflow property to see if those would help out but they don't