# virtual keyboard popup onfocus of a text field

Tags: javascript, html, input, textarea

**EDIT: this feat is impossible. since then I have given up. I shall not delete this question, but rather leave it up right here so future users can see a relevant result to their query on google regarding a similar thing**

- Goal: Either make a `textarea` bring up the virtual keyboard when focused(with js) OR make a `input[type=text]` have multiple lines AND bring the virtual keyboard
  (I believe answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037548/how-can-make-an-inputtype-text-element-to-work-as-textarea) but with unsatisfactory results.) (If anyone knows of fully compatible ways to multiple-line-ify an `input[type=text]` please tell me)
- Expected results: virtual keyboard popup when focusing the input OR textarea fields (via javascript with no user trigger).
- Real results: caret appears in text field but keyboard remains unseen.
- Here's what I'm trying on a textarea:

```
document.elementFromPoint(document.querySelector("textarea").getBoundingClientRect().x, document.querySelector("textarea").getBoundingClientRect().y).dispatchEvent(click);
```

- **Please don't make irrelevant comments about my code organization**
- @WaisKamal can you show me your code since you said it works?
- HTML(no CSS):

```
<textarea>textarea</textarea>
<input type="text" value="input" />
<script>
//document.elementFromPoint(document.querySelector("textarea").getBoundingClientRect().x, document.querySelector("textarea").getBoundingClientRect().y).dispatchEvent("click");
document.querySelector("input").focus();
document.querySelector("input").click();
</script>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on nothing works? Is there no keyboard? Is there only one line? Are you unable to type?

Comment: just no keyboard popup (on textarea)

Comment: If you use `<input type="text">`, does the keyboard show up?

Comment: Also, could you share some of your HTML and CSS?

Comment: no. it does not show up

Comment: for html and css i will add them

Comment: Note `dispatchEvent` takes an Event object argument, not a string. You might try calling the  [`HTMLElement.click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method, or (more likely) the  [HTMLELement.focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus) method to bring up the keyboard.

Comment: @traktor yes correct but those methods do not bring up the virtual keyboard on textarea and, suprisingly, neither on input[type=text]

Comment: You need to add `type="text"` to the input: `<input value="input" type="text">` and remove the closing tag; there is no closing tag for inputs. See if that fixes it.

Comment: still dosent bring up keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inputmode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) to determine how a virtual keyboard behaves

```html
<textarea>textarea</textarea>
<input type="text" value="input" inputmode='text'/>
<script>
//document.elementFromPoint(document.querySelector("textarea").getBoundingClientRect().x, document.querySelector("textarea").getBoundingClientRect().y).dispatchEvent("click");
document.querySelector("input").focus();
document.querySelector("input").click();
</script>
```

*Edit*

I'm still testing this out, it seem to give some mixed results in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au9Lg6m2/2/) that I'm currently testing right now, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not

*Edit 2 *

It seems to have the same results without specifying the `inputmode` It does not work the first time the page loads but if I click somewhere on the page, it works every time I click run.

I'm **only speculating** here but it seems like the keyboard does not pop up without the page receiving some user interaction first, maybe this is intentional for security reasons but I didn't find any docs saying so.

As for you other question you can give a `div` or other container element  [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) to have multiple rows / any dimensions you want.

-

Here is another questions and some answers to the same problem though a bit old, [Show virtual keyboard on mobile phones in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837543/show-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-phones-in-javascript)

-

All in all it does not seem possible so show a virtual keyboard without some user interaction.

Comment: `inputmode` certainly dosen't work for me however