# Html - long textinput

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make text in text input look like textarea .I want the text to start from the top and goes back to line at the end but i don't want to use textarea

textinput :
[image: textinput]
textarea :
[image: textarea]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can make an input\[type=text\] element to work as textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037548/how-can-make-an-inputtype-text-element-to-work-as-textarea)

Comment: Tried it its still the same

Comment: Curious why you would want to opt for a text `input` instead of `textarea` here? They're separately available for many reasons, one being the input text is only meant to accept one line.

Comment: well i want to use it in a form and the option value="" didn't work;

Comment: `textarea` is literally made for usage in forms just as much as `input` is but for exactly this scenario. Except you don't set `value="blah"` as an element attribute, you set the content value directly (because it's for exactly this type of multi-line scenario) like `<textarea>HEY I AM SOME MULTI LINE CONTENT</textarea>` and then if you change it programmatically it would be like `document.getElementsByTag('textarea')[0].value = 'HEY MORE FORMATTED MULTI-LINE CONTENT AS THE VALUE, WEEE!';`

Comment: By spec, `<input />` is a single-line text field from which line-breaks are automatically removed and doesn't allow wrapping in multiple lines, whereas `<textarea />` that supports a multi-line plain-text editing control for free-form text. Both can be semantically used in a `<form />`, and because you'd need _some_ JavaScript to handle the data, you can certainly manage the inner text values for both. In this case, `<textarea />` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use `<input>` tag with multiline. If `<textarea>` is not an option, then the only option is to use `contenteditable` attribute

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 230px; height: 230px; word-break: break-word;"  >
   some text
</div>
```