# Ionic 2 Alerts input resize

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I am using ionic 2 framework and wanted to know if anyone could help. 
I am trying to have alert inputs be more than just one line or be textareas instead of just one line inputs any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert component in ionic2 just support input and you can not set row property for input. check [more-than-1-row-in-input-type-textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089182/more-than-1-row-in-input-type-textarea).

instead the [AlertController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/) document recommend to use [modals](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#modals).